# How to get all post information from a facebook fan page

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

Is there a method with the sdk of facebook in php to get all post( with likes , shares , comments ) of a fan page  ?

Comment: yes https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/object/likes